# killProcess doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, process, android-ndk, kill, kill-process

I have Android NDK project, the problem is that sometimes on some devices running Android 2.x (but in rare cases even 4.0), it is impossible to terminate the current process with android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()). I know it sounds crazy, but instead of termination, application just hangs. Standard ANR (Application Not Responding) dialog is shown 10-15 seconds later, but... I'm unable to terminate process even if I click the "Force Close" button in the dialog! The only way to terminate application is to go to Settings/Applications/Manage Application and click the "Force Stop" button there.

There are many lines in the log:
E/JavaBinder(175): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

So is it possible to somehow force-force-force-kill the current process on Android programmatically? The solution should work on Android 2.2+

Comment: Have you added kill permissions : ´ <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>´

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to "force-force-force-kill the current process on Android programmatically" in the first place.

Comment: @user2439755: KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES is for killBackgroundProcesses, but I'm using android.os.Process.killProcess (also tried exit(0) in C/C++).
CommonsWare: Killing the current process is a correct way to terminate NDK application, my application is a game.

Comment: When the process is in the unkillable state, what does `adb shell ps -t | grep <pid>` show?

Comment: "Killing the current process is a correct way to terminate NDK application" -- got a link to documentation stating this?